# AS3 Move and Rotate a object to a point in 3D space

Tags: actionscript-3, math, 3d, away3d

**Hello,**

I trying to move a object in stage 3D (I'm using away3d framework) to a point in space (vector 3d), its fine and working, but I want that object turn it "front face" to that point, so it will be aways "looking" and "walk" to it.

**The code that move the object:**

```
Tweener.addTween(
  mainReference.carHolder, 
  { 
    time:.1, 
    x:points[point].x, 
    y:points[point].y, 
    z:points[point].z, 
    transition:"Linear", 
    onComplete:function():void 
    { 
      moveCar(point + 1); 
    } 
  });
```

**What I already try:**

```
var angleX:Number = Vector3D.angleBetween(
  new Vector3D(
    mainReference.carHolder.x, 
    mainReference.carHolder.y, 
    mainReference.carHolder.z), 
  new Vector3D(
    mainReference.carHolder.x, 
    points[point].y, 
    points[point].z)
) * 180 / Math.PI;

var angleY:Number = Vector3D.angleBetween(
  new Vector3D(
    mainReference.carHolder.x, 
    mainReference.carHolder.y, 
    mainReference.carHolder.z), 
  new Vector3D(
    points[point].x, 
    mainReference.carHolder.y, 
    points[point].z)
) * 180 / Math.PI;

var angleZ:Number = Vector3D.angleBetween(
  new Vector3D(
    mainReference.carHolder.x, 
    mainReference.carHolder.y, 
    mainReference.carHolder.z), 
  new Vector3D(
    points[point].x, 
    points[point].y, 
    mainReference.carHolder.z)
) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

---

```
var angle:Number = Vector3D.angleBetween(
  new Vector3D(
    mainReference.carHolder.x, 
    mainReference.carHolder.y, 
    mainReference.carHolder.z), 
  new Vector3D(
    points[point].x, 
    points[point].y, 
    points[point].z)
) / 180 * Math.PI;
```

---

```
mainReference.carHolder.eulers = new Vector3D(
  points[point].x, 
  points[point].y, 
  points[point].z);
mainReference.carHolder.rotateTo(
  points[point].x, 
  points[point].y, 
  points[point].z);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [lookAt()](http://away3d.com/livedocs/away3d/4.0/away3d/core/base/Object3D.html#lookAt%28%29) method?

From the docs:

---

**lookAt()**
public function lookAt(target:Vector3D, upAxis:Vector3D = null):void
Rotates the 3d object around to face a point defined relative to the local coordinates of the parent ObjectContainer3D.

Parameters

target:Vector3D — The vector defining the point to be looked at

upAxis:Vector3D (default = null) — An optional vector used to define the desired up orientation of the 3d object after rotation has occurred

---

This should allow you to have your object look at the target position while traveling to it.